# TLE in SPOJ ACTIV

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, dynamic-programming, binary-search

I am trying out SPOJ ACTIV. (http://www.spoj.com/problems/ACTIV/) My algorithm works in `n log n` but still time limit exceeded is coming. Could someone help me please.

We are supposed to find the number of non-empty non-overlapping subsets of activities a person can do in intervals marked (start,end). I am first sorting by start time. Then im doing a binary search on the end in the rest of the array while maintaining the sum in a sum variable(dp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility> 
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef pair<long long,long long> p;
vector<long long> ans;
vector<long long> cuml_sum;


int comp(p a,p b){
  return a.first<b.first;
}

long long mod(long long sum,long long powe){
  return (sum-(sum/powe)*powe);
}

int bins(vector<p> arr,long long start,long long end,long long search){
  if(start>end)
    return start;
  int mid = (start+end)/2;
  if(arr[mid].first==search)
    return mid;
  else if(arr[mid].first<search)
    return bins(arr,mid+1,end,search);
  else
    return bins(arr,start,mid-1,search);
}

void reverse(string s){
  int i=0;
  int j=s.length()-1;
  while(j>=0){
  cout<<s[j];
  j--;
 }
 }

void process(long long num)
{
  string s="";
  int i=0;
  while(i<8){
    s+=num%10+'0';
    num/=10;
    if(num==0){
      while(i<7){
        s+='0';
        i++;
      }
    break;
    }
    i++;
  }
  reverse(s);
  cout<<"\n";
}



long long func(vector<p> arr)
{

int n=arr.size();
ans[n-1]=1;
long long sum=ans[n-1];
cuml_sum[n-1]=ans[n-1];
for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
  int j=bins(arr,i+1,n-1,arr[i].second);
  if(j>n-1)
  {
    ans[j]=0;
    cuml_sum[j]=0;
  }
  ans[i]=1+cuml_sum[j];
  cuml_sum[i]=ans[i]+cuml_sum[i+1];
  sum+=ans[i];
}
return mod(sum,(long long)pow(10,8));
}

int main(void){
  vector<p> arr;
  int test,n;
 for(int i=0;i<100000;i++){
 ans.push_back(0);
 cuml_sum.push_back(0);
 }
 long long a,b;
 while(1){
  cin>>n;
  if(n==-1)
   return 0;
  for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
   cin>>a>>b;
   arr.push_back(p(a,b));

  }

 sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),comp);
 process(func(arr));
 arr.clear();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: give us a brief explanation of the problem and your solution.

Comment: We are supposed to find the number of non-empty non-overlapping subsets of activities a person can do in intervals marked (start,end). I am first sorting by start time . Then im doing a binary search on the end in the rest of the array and am maintaining the sum in sum variable(dp)

Comment: i don't understand the example input, output. How come the output of first test is 12, from what I understand it should be 3.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2: The result is not the size of the maximum non-overlapping subset, but the number of possible subsets.

Comment: Not related to TLE, but the fact that you should only output the last eight digits is a big hint that you should probably be using modular arithmetic throughout, not only when you print the number.